# Not able to convert language in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, i18n-gem

I have included given code in en.yml file

```
en:
 spree:
  buy_now: Buy Now
```

and in my index.html.haml

```
.buy-now.text-center
 = spree.t(:buy_now)
```

but its not converting the language everytime it shows me Buy Now when I change language to FRANCIAS then too it do not change. Please guide me how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have this file set up?

**config/locales/fr.yml**

```
fr:
 spree:
  buy_now: "Acheter maintenant"
```